# Ubuntu Server/Network Advice

Tags: networking, server, users

What I basically want to is make so that any one of my family members can log on at any of our Pc/Laptops and still assess their files. I know kinda of know what to do but not completely. Would this be called a server or a network. If any one could help/guide me I'll be very thankful.

PandaGlasses

Answer (score 0):

Try [Samba](http://www.samba.org/) Here is the [Official Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/samba.html) from start to finish. Also [consider this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wUfzdiE4m8) as a re-enforcement which greatly helped.

Comment: It's half way of what i want to do. I want be able to log in from boot up with the same username and password on any pc and not have to make separate accounts on each device. Can Samba do that? if so I can't find any sign of it. Thanks anyway